# RecyclerView View Items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to show 2 columns in a RecyclerView, but they show in 1 column like this photo:

[image: 1]

How can I show my view in 2 columns?

I try it in my code with 2 columns:

```
rcv_pro.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
```

but they don't show in 2 columns.

i find a soulotion for show in 2 culmn , i can fix it whit clear this code :
" menuList_info_models.clear(); "
but i have a new probem now , when i clear that cod , my items in recyclerview is mess , any time i scrole in recyclerview , my items change

[image: 2]

```java
public class MultiItem_Music_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();
    Context context;

    private final static int MUSIC_CAT = 1;
    private final static int MUSIC_ADA = 2;
    private ArrayList<MenuList_Info_Model> menuList_info_models;
    private ArrayList<Cat_Model> cat_models;
    private Music_Adapter adapter;
    private List<MenuList_Info_Model> personList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ListAdapter mAdapter;
    private ArrayList<MenuList_Info_Model> music_data;
    public GridLayoutManager manager ;

    public MultiItem_Music_Adapter(ArrayList<Object> objects, Context context) {
        Log.e("MyLog","farzad");
        this.objects = objects;
        this.context = context;
        if (menuList_info_models == null)
            menuList_info_models = new ArrayList<MenuList_Info_Model>();
        if (cat_models == null) cat_models = new ArrayList<Cat_Model>();

        adapter = new Music_Adapter(menuList_info_models, this.context);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder ;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view;
        switch (viewType) {
            case MUSIC_CAT:
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.music_cat_item, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new Music_cat_ViewHolder(view);
                break;
            case MUSIC_ADA:
                view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.music_item_multi, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new Multi_item_ViewHolder(view);
                break;
            default:
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.music_item_multi, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new Multi_item_ViewHolder(view);
                break;
        }
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.e("hamid_ali", "---------------------");
        switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
            case MUSIC_CAT:
                Cat_Config((Music_cat_ViewHolder) holder,position);
                break;
            case MUSIC_ADA:
                item_Config((Multi_item_ViewHolder) holder,position);
                break;
        }
    }
    private void item_Config(Multi_item_ViewHolder item_viewHolder,int pos) {
        MenuList_Info_Model menuList_info_model = (MenuList_Info_Model) objects.get(pos);
        menuList_info_models.clear();
        menuList_info_models.add(menuList_info_model);
        Log.e("hamid_st",menuList_info_models.size() +"");
        manager = new GridLayoutManager(this.context, 2, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        item_viewHolder.rcv_multi.setLayoutManager(manager);
            item_viewHolder.rcv_multi.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void Cat_Config(Music_cat_ViewHolder musicCatViewHolder,int pos) {
        Cat_Model cat_model = (Cat_Model) objects.get(pos);
        musicCatViewHolder.txt_cat_name.setText(cat_model.getMenu_name());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return objects.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (objects.get(position) instanceof Cat_Model) {
            return MUSIC_CAT;
        } else {

            return MUSIC_ADA;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post you xml code

Comment: no problem in xml

Comment: how are you sure that there's no problem in xml ?

Comment: testing ! problem in code menuList_info_models.clear();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i must be  create two ViewHolder  see more code

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    class ViewHolder0 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ...
        public ViewHolder0(View itemView){
        ...
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ...
        public ViewHolder2(View itemView){
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // Just as an example, return 0 or 2 depending on position
        // Note that unlike in ListView adapters, types don't have to be contiguous
        return position % 2 * 2;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
         switch (viewType) {
             case 0: return new ViewHolder0(...);
             case 2: return new ViewHolder2(...);
             ...
         }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
            case 0:
                ViewHolder0 viewHolder0 = (ViewHolder0)holder;
                ...
                break;

            case 2:
                ViewHolder2 viewHolder2 = (ViewHolder2)holder;
                ...
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use **[GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html)**

> set `GridLayoutManager` to your `RecyclerView` uisng below code

```
GridLayoutManager  gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 2);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

here is link how to use [**GridLayoutManager**](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-gridlayoutmanager-with-recyclerview-in-material-design/) with `RecyclerView`

Answer (score 1):

```
RvAdapter MultiItem_Music_Adapter ;
RecyclerView rcv_pro;
MultiItem_Music_Adapter = new MultiItem_Music_Adapter (getActivity());
rcv_pro.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2)); 
rcv_pro.setAdapter(MultiItem_Music_Adapter );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for 2 columns :-

```
mRecycler.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(YourActivity.this, 2));
mRecycler.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

It is mendatory to setLayoutMangaer with your recyclerview otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the two columns of an items in `RecyclerView` via `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` too.

From **[documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html)**, you can use following method:

> StaggeredGridLayoutManager(int spanCount, int orientation)

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager yourStaggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
yourRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
```

Or directly:

```
yourRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
```