# How to create a LinearLayout programmatically using a for loop

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am trying to create a `LinearLayout` programmatically from information contained in an `Array`.

Let me explain :

I create a professional application that will not be on PlayStore.

I have the following Array, manually populated, (a kind of global variable):

```
    static final String[][] reseaux = new String[][] {

            {"Net1","192.168.0.1"},
            {"Net2","192.168.10.1"},
            {"Net3","192.168.20.1"},
            {"Net4","192.168.30.1"}
    };
```

For some customers, it contains only one entry :

```
    static final String[][] reseaux = new String[][] {

        {"Net1","192.168.0.1"}
    };
```

According to the `Array` containing only one entry, I created the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/welcome"
android:layout_gravity="center"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
tools:ignore="Overdraw">


<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:baselineAligned="false">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTest"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the code :

```
        LinearLayout l = findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutTest);
    for (int i = 0; i < reseaux.length; ++i) {

        final int id = i;
        ImageButton resBtn = new ImageButton(this);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM);
        tv.setText(reseaux[i][0]);

        resBtn.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.button_reseaux));
        resBtn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));
        l.addView(resBtn);
        l.addView(tv);

        resBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Check network
                if (CheckNetworkStatus.isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext())) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            HomeReseauActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    BASE_URL = null;
                    nomReseau = null;
                    BASE_URL = reseaux[id][1];
                    nomReseau = reseaux[id][0];
                } else {
                    //Error message if no network connexion
                    if (toastMessage != null) toastMessage.cancel();
                    toastMessage = Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, getString(R.string.networkError), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toastMessage.show();
                }

            }
        });
```

Give me the following result that suits me perfectly :

[image]

Now, when I have multiple entries in my `Array`, here's what I get :

[image]

This does not suit me. I will like horizontal lines of three icons. When a line is filled, it creates a new line of three icons, etc.

Here is a quick edit with paint to demonstrate what I want:

[image]

I think the solution must be simple .. but I can not get this result.

Be indulgent with my code, I learn everything by myself and there is surely a better way to write :-)

Hoping someone can help me!

Comment: use `GridView` .

Comment: better would be RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager

Comment: The better way to user **Recycler view** for the same

Comment: Use **[recyclerView with GridLayoutManager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46291935/7666442)**

Comment: You probably have to use recyclerView with GridLayoutManager

Comment: Thank you very much for your very helpful advice, I have been successful with RecyclerView and GridLayoutManager :-)

Comment: @Joel Put in an answer or delete :)

Comment: On the plus side, this question did get me looking at GridLayout for just such a bit of ui i need to write. Now seeing "BASE_URL" in that snippet is horrifying for a whole new set of issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments of my question, the solution was to use RecyclerView and GridLayoutManager.

For future readers, this **[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46291916/recyclerview-view-items/46291935#46291935)** has helped me a lot!

Thanks to everyone who answered my question.