# How to implement horizontal grid recycler view by horizontal span

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How to implement horizontal grid recycler view by horizontal span like this:

**What i want**

[image]

I use `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` and `GridLayoutManager` but the result is:

**Result**

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46291935/7666442

Comment: Use `GridLayoutManager` in place of `LayoutManager` for horizontal `RecyclerView`.

Comment: @NileshRathod

Thank you for your answer. But GridLayoutManager  and StaggeredGridLayoutManager  does not fix my problem. I edited the post.

Comment: @SavinSharma

Thank you for your answer. But GridLayoutManager  and StaggeredGridLayoutManager  does not fix my problem. I edited the post.

Comment: @AlirezaEs than try with [FlexboxLayoutManager](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout#flexboxlayoutmanager-within-recyclerview)

Comment: @AlirezaEs Share your code snippet for more understanding.

Comment: @AlirezaEs did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **StaggeredGridLayoutManager** with the **span** value 3 and **horizontal** orientation as below

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But GridLayoutManager  and StaggeredGridLayoutManager  does not fix my problem. I edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
GridLayoutManager(context, NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
```

If you want to keep specific number or rows calculate the number of columns dynamically